# How to ANOVA a specific date?

Tags: r

I would like to know how to set my ANOVA to a specific date from my data, i.e. day 16. My ANOVA is set to:

```
###Compute two-way ANOVA test ##
model = gls(Height ~ Temp + pH + Temp * pH,
            data=my_data_daily,
            method="REML")
```

and my data is read as follows and I'm using dplyr and ggpubr, and I'm sure there's a way to read the data at that specific date:

```
#Reading the data



my_data_daily  <- read.csv("mydata.csv",sep=",")

 


#check your data (first few rows)
head(my_data_daily)
tail(my_data_daily)



#check the structure
str(my_data_daily)
```

Comment: `gls` is not in base R packages and when I search for it, I get "generalized least squares". What libraries are you loading when you do the above? Also need to provide a small representative data set and include in your question, e.g. with `dput(my_data_daily)`

Comment: `gls` is in `nlme` (which is a "recommended" package, albeit not "base")

Comment: Without a sample of your data or at least the results of `str()` it is hard to say, but the manual page, (see `?gls`) indicates that it supports the `subset=` argument which should allow you to restrict your analysis to data from a particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, basically have to select day 16 from my data:

```
dayspecificdata <- my_data_daily[ which(my_data_daily$Day=='16'), ]
```